# stramlit table produced with df.to_html

Tags: python, jquery-ui-sortable, streamlit

Looking for solution to sort a table produced with df.to_html in streamlit. I know streamlit can produce dynamically sortable table only if we don't use df.to_html but due to some reason I am bound to use it. now I am totally lost on how to make this table sortable!!

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.read_csv('data/AUDCAD_1h.csv')

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

st.write(df.to_html(escape=False, index=False),
         unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP6rz.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: "_due to some reason I am bound to use it._" Tell us the reason.  "_only if we don't use df.to_html_" Yes, that's right, the `.to_html()` precludes offering the sort feature   you're interested in.

Comment: Becoz the script I am using has 300+ codes and uses .to_htm() to produce the final filtered table.

Comment: Sort the dataframe first before you proceed to use `df.to_html`

Comment: That is one option. but I wanted to make this table interactive so that table can be sorted at any time on any column by clicking on its table header..... I am sure there must be a way but don't know how to do it.